# Using DAYS() Function makes it off by 1 day

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've made a spreadsheet that splits out grant amounts by year, using the DAYS() function. However, it seems to be off by a day on random ones -- even when I add an extra day.

See the table below. Any row where Total Sum (Test) does not equal 100,000 is wrong

| Start Date | End Date | Amount Granted | Per Day | Total Sum (Test) | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 | 2027 | 2028 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/8/2021 | 11/6/2028 | 100000 | 36.9276218611521 | 100000 | 7644.01772525849 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 11484.4903988183 |
| 04/05/2023 | 12/12/2028 | 100000 | 48.1231953801732 | 100000 | 0 | 0 | 13041.385948027 | 17564.9663137632 | 17564.9663137632 | 17564.9663137632 | 17564.9663137632 | 16698.7487969201 |
| 04/06/2024 | 12/13/2026 | 100000 | 101.936799184506 | 100101.936799185 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 27522.9357798165 | 37206.9317023446 | 35372.0693170234 | 0 | 0 |
| 04/20/2021 | 04/21/2023 | 100000 | 136.798905608755 | 100136.798905609 | 35020.5198358413 | 49931.6005471956 | 15184.6785225718 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/12/2023 | 03/12/2024 | 100000 | 253.807106598985 | 100253.807106599 | 0 | 0 | 81979.6954314721 | 18274.1116751269 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/12/2021 | 02/12/2022 | 100000 | 273.972602739726 | 100273.97260274 | 88493.1506849315 | 11780.8219178082 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/12/2024 | 02/12/2025 | 100000 | 273.224043715847 | 100273.224043716 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 88524.5901639344 | 11748.6338797814 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 01/01/2023 | 12/31/2023 | 100000 | 274.725274725275 | 100000 | 0 | 0 | 100000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Here is the formula I used (I saved it as a named function)

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(givendate) >= YEAR(startdate), YEAR(givendate) <= YEAR(enddate)), IF(YEAR(enddate) = YEAR(startdate), total, IF(YEAR(startdate) = YEAR(givendate), ((DAYS(givendate,startdate) + 1) * (total/ DAYS(enddate,startdate))), IF((YEAR(enddate) = YEAR(givendate)), (DAYS(enddate,(DATE(YEAR(givendate),1,1))) + 1) * (total/ DAYS(enddate,startdate)), 365 * (total/ DAYS(enddate,startdate))))),0)
```

[Find the spreadsheet here:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iyNB5eXXTQTTi1rvM4NvEYZob81kZsqK/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115912623506713100477&rtpof=true&sd=true)

I tried adapting the formula to use a TODAY() function for this issue. It fixed the issue except for some other grants

See the table below. Any row where Total Sum (Test) does not equal 100,000 is wrong

| Start Date | End Date | Amount Granted | Per Day | Total Sum (Test) | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 | 2027 | 2028 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/8/2021 | 11/6/2028 | 100000 | 36.9276218611521 | 99963.0723781389 | 7607.09010339734 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 13478.5819793205 | 11484.4903988183 |
| 04/05/2023 | 12/12/2028 | 100000 | 48.1231953801732 | 100000 | 0 | 0 | 13041.385948027 | 17564.9663137632 | 17564.9663137632 | 17564.9663137632 | 17564.9663137632 | 16698.7487969201 |
| 04/20/2021 | 04/21/2023 | 100000 | 136.798905608755 | 100000. | 34883.7209302326 | 49931.6005471956 | 15184.6785225718 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/12/2023 | 03/12/2024 | 100000 | 253.807106598985 | 100253.807106599 | 0 | 0 | 81979.6954314721 | 18274.1116751269 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/12/2021 | 02/12/2022 | 100000 | 273.972602739726 | 100000 | 88219.1780821918 | 11780.8219178082 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/12/2024 | 02/12/2025 | 100000 | 273.224043715847 | 100000. | 0 | 0 | 0 | 88251.3661202186 | 11748.6338797814 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 01/01/2023 | 12/31/2023 | 100000 | 274.725274725275 | 100000 | 0 | 0 | 100000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Here is the adapted formula

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(givendate) >= YEAR(startdate), YEAR(givendate) <= YEAR(enddate)), IF(YEAR(enddate) = YEAR(startdate), total, IF((YEAR(startdate) = YEAR(givendate)), (IF(YEAR(TODAY()) = YEAR(givendate), (DAYS(givendate,startdate) + 1) * (total/ DAYS(enddate,startdate)), DAYS(givendate,startdate) * (total/ DAYS(enddate,startdate)))), IF((YEAR(enddate) = YEAR(givendate)), (DAYS(enddate,(DATE(YEAR(givendate),1,1))) + 1) * (total/ DAYS(enddate,startdate)), 365 * (total/ DAYS(enddate,startdate))))),0)
```

[Find the spreadsheet here:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iyNB5eXXTQTTi1rvM4NvEYZob81kZsqK/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115912623506713100477&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `=DAYS(C15,B15)` gives you *364* days and `=D15/DAYS(C15,B15)` gives *274.725274725275* amount per day while it should be `365` days and *273.9726027* amount per day. Correct formula for amount:

```
=$D15/DAYS($C15+1,$B15)
```

Also you multiply all full year by *365* while 2024 is leap year with *366* days. There are more mistakes with +1 in `DAYS` formula.

Similar to your formula (in `G8`):

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(G$6)=YEAR($B8),YEAR($C8)=YEAR($B8)),DAYS($C8+1,$B8),IF(YEAR($B8)=YEAR(G$6),DAYS(G$6+1,$B8),IF(YEAR($C8)=YEAR(G$6),DAYS(G$6+1,DATE(YEAR(G$6),1,1))-DAYS(G$6,$C8),IF(AND(YEAR($B8)<YEAR(G$6),YEAR($C8)>YEAR(G$6)),DAYS(G$6+1,DATE(YEAR(G$6),1,1)),0))))*$D8/DAYS($C8+1,$B8)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out; the formula goes into `Cell_G7`:*

```js
=map(B7:B,C7:C,D7:D,lambda(b,c,d,if(counta({b,c,d})<>3,,let(Σ,days(c,b-1), Γ,hstack(sequence(Σ,1,b),wrapcols(d/Σ,Σ,d/Σ)),
     map(G6:N6,lambda(Λ,sum(ifna(filter(index(Γ,,2),year(index(Γ,,1))=year(Λ))))))))))
```

- *Make sure to clear out the whole range `G7:N` of any existing formulas/data so as for the above formula to expand freely downwards+right_side*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update, I ended up using the following answer:

```
=let( 
  start, $B8, 
  end, $C8, 
  perDay, $E8, 
  year, to_text(G$6), 
  numDaysInYear, (year & "-12-31") - (year & "-1-1") + 1, 
  numDaysWithinPeriod, iferror( 
    rows(filter( 
      sequence(numDaysInYear), 
      isbetween( 
        sequence(numDaysInYear, 1, year & "-1-1"), 
        start, 
        end 
      ) 
    )), 
    0 
  ),     
  numDaysWithinPeriod * perDay 
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).